# Возвращается пустой span

Tags: python, парсер, lxml, beautiful-soup

Есть проблема с использованием BeautifulSoup

```
page = urlopen('http://weather.nsu.ru').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup (page, "lxml")
spans = soup.find_all('span')
print(str(spans[0]))
```

Здесь в коде хочу получить элемент с текущей температурой, но все время получаю на выходе пустой элемент.

```
<span id="temp"></span>
```

Может кто подскажет в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `span` действительно путой:

```
  <body>
    <h1>Температура около НГУ <span id="temp"></span></h1>
    ...
```

Решение: парсим http://weather.nsu.ru/loadata.php:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'http://weather.nsu.ru/loadata.php'
r = requests.get(url)

found = re.findall(r'window.document.title\s*=[^\-\+\d\.]*([\-\+\d\.]*)', r.text)
if found:
    print(found[0])
```

Результат:

```
-9.9
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, как раз в этот момент шел по этому пути решения :)